# Hidden Markov Model observing sequences

Tags: probability, predictive-models, likelihood, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have been trying to understand Hidden Markov Models but I often find myself confused. I have discussed with my tutor for further help however, he is often rude and does not help and so I have decided to turn to the community.

I am trying to determine the probability of observing the following sequences: AABGA, ABBGT.

From what I understand based on the data is that the states are the letters, A,A,B,G,T and the emissions are the numbers 1,2,3...5. I am wondering if I have correctly mapped this Markov model given the data and correctly found the probabilities of the sequences?. I think my confusion stems from the emissions and the way the observational probabilities are displayed. I feel it should be $P(1|A)$ and not $P(A|1)$ although I have been told that this does not matter. Would appreciate any insight into where I might have gone wrong or if I have correctly approached this.

[image]

Markov Model mapped:
[image]

Probability of observing sequences:

AABGA

$1,2,2,4,4 = 0.3 * 0.7 * 0.1 * 0.5 * 0.2 = 0.21%$

$1,2,2,2,2 = 0.3 * 0.7 * 0.1 * 0.3 * 0.5 = 0.315%$

$1,2,2,2,2 = 0.3 * 0.7 * 0.1 * 0.3 * 0.1 = 0.063%$

$2,2,2,4,4 = 0.4 * 0.5 * 0.1 * 0.5 * 0.2 = 0.2%$

$2,2,2,4,4 = 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.5 * 0.2 = 0.04%$

$2,2,2,2,2 = 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.3 * 0.5 = 0.06%$

$2,2,2,2,2 = 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.3 * 0.1 = 0.012%$

$P(AABGA)$ = 0.21% + 0.315% + 0.063% + 0.2% + 0.04% + 0.06% + 0.012% = $0.9%$

ABBGT

$2,2,2,4,4 = 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.5 * 0.2 = 0.04%$

$2,2,2,2,3 = 0.4 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.3 * 0.5 = 0.06%$

$P(ABBGT)$ = 0.04% + 0.06% = $0.1%$

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Sycorax The question was if I had correctly mapped the Hidden Markov model and correctly determined the observational probability of the sequences. This would help me understand if my approach/understanding was right and will indirectly confirm/answer if $P(1|A)$ or $P(A|1)$ makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a question (a sentence ending in "?").

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks for the response. I have edited the post.